# SQLite Database Locking in JUnit Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, sqlite, junit

I am running JUnit 4.10 on Eclipse 3.7. I am doing database testing: database used is SQLite3 with [sqlitejdbc](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/). I tried running tests on both windows and linux and here are my observations:

- On Windows 7 x64, the tests run faster (~0.6s per test). I do get errors about "Cannot open database file". They appear to be intermittent (sometimes the same test can pass once while the next run fails)
- On Ubuntu 11.10 x64, the tests are slow (~3s per test). I get errors about "database locked". Unlike Windows' errors being intermittent, here, errors seems to happen on the same test/file and once the lock error occur all following tests fails.

**UPDATE**

You can find the code for tests on [GitHub](https://github.com/jiewmeng/reborn/tree/master/src/unittests/dal). I think the problem might be something to do with how my `@BeforeClass`, `@Before` and test suites are setup

I have a Test Suite like

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ DataAccessTests.class, SimpleQueryTests.class, ... })
public class DataAccessTestSuite {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpDatabase() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {    
        DataAccess.setEnvironment(DataAccess.DATABASE_TESTING);
        Connection conn = DataAccess.getConn();

        // truncate tables: simply DELETE statements
        truncateTables(conn);

        // insert test data, INSERT statements
        insertTestData(conn);
    }
```

Then in my Test classes I had a `@Before` that calls setup also.

```
public class EventsDataAccessTests {

    @Before
public void setup() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    DataAccessTestSuite.setUpDatabase();
}
```

I was thinking I still want to setup my database in case I don't want to call the entire suite. I think the problem is something to do with this, but I am not sure how exactly it causes a problem. It appears that even if I call the individual test class, my setup for the suite runs? Or if not, how can I insure it is run once in case the test is not called from the Suite?

*-- Old Post Removed --*

Comment: Do you run unit test concurrently?

Comment: I run my tests using Eclipse, no multiple instances of eclipse or anything like that, so tests should not run concurrently?

Comment: If I have something like `@SuiteClasses({ DataAccessTests.class, SimpleQueryTests.class, SimpleInsertTests.class, SimpleUpdateTests.class, ... })` are the individual test classes run concurrently?

Comment: Do you use maven? Usually parallel execution should be allowed by some parameters, e.g. `<parallel>classes</parallel>`.
Do you use threads in your tests?

Comment: @kan, I do not use `<parallel>` in my tests. No I don't use any threading in my tests

Comment: Do you close all result-sets/connections/transactions/etc during a test tear down and before the next test starts?

Comment: Hey that's my answer :-)

Comment: I am using a Singleton for the database connection, so I didn't close the connection, but I think I need to check I closed result sets and statements ... but I should have... I updated my post with some observations too

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't reviewed your code extensively, so I might have missed something, but it seems you don't close the connection, leaving it to the GC to do it later.

Comment: This does indeed sound like a race condition between the garbage collector and the write lock on the target file, exactly as @sixfeetsix suggests. The thing is, I can't see why you're using a file-backed database at all for these tests. My first port of call for database-shaped unit testing in Java is actually [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), because it doesn't require something as flaky as a file lock. Bonus: it's more resilient to concurrent testing, exactly as queried at the top of this comment thread. :)

Comment: @MrGomez, I am using SQLite as its something users will not need to install when using the app. HSQLDB sounds like a good alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure no more than one thread at a time tries to have a write-lock on the sqlite database. For an overview of what I mean by that, read

[(5) Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same application access a single database file at the same time?](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

So when you say:

> If I run the test by itself, it passes. When trying to run the whole
>   suite it fails

I think it's fair to assume that the write-lock is not released by perhaps a connection object while another one tries to acquire it. **So even if you don't use threads, perhaps the GC doesn't get to the connection object of a previous test before another test creates another connection object.**

Maybe you can post some of these tests to help better understand what might be going wrong.

**UPDATE:**

Shouldn't you close the connection here?:

```
public static void tearDownDatabase() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection conn = DataAccess.getConn();
    truncateTables(conn);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the keen diagnosis. Occasionally, we all inadvertently cause concurrency problems. :)